# Python と OpenCV で回転した画像をもとに戻す処理方法

Tags: python, python3, opencv

PythonのOpenCVを使って回転した画像をもとの角度に戻したいです

最終目標は、画像に角度付きの矩形を複数個描画することです
そのために描画画像を回転->矩形を描画->逆向きの角度に回転 という処理で実現しようと思いましたが、最初の画像回転ではみ出た個所を補正する方法がわかりませんでした

回転は角度と中心座標を指定します

使用しているPythonは3.7.9、OpenCVは4.6系です

Comment: 扱い方や角度にもよると思いますが、通常はビットマップ画像の回転は、劣化を伴なうはずです。
それを繰り返し行なうよりは、metropolis さんの回答のように、矩形の方を回転させて描画するのがよいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 最終目標は、画像に角度付きの矩形を複数個描画することです

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
  
img = cv2.imread('flower.png')
rect1 = cv2.RotatedRect((275, 250), (150, 100), 30)
rect2 = cv2.RotatedRect((150, 150), (100, 70), 80)
rect3 = cv2.RotatedRect((450, 200), (200, 150), -10)
cv2.polylines(img, rect1.points().astype(np.int32).reshape(1, 4, 2), True, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.polylines(img, rect2.points().astype(np.int32).reshape(1, 4, 2), True, (255, 0, 0), 2)
cv2.polylines(img, rect3.points().astype(np.int32).reshape(1, 4, 2), True, (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imwrite('image.png', img)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: RotatedRectを実行しようとしたところ、module 'cv2' has no attribute 'RotatedRect' と表示され処理が停止しました
解決方法をご存じでしょうか?

Comment: OpenCVのバージョンを4.8系に上げることで、スクリプトを実行できました

Answer (score 1):

（そもそも やりたいことに対してその方法はどうなのか？ という点については既に別の回答が付いているで置いておくとして…）

> 最初の画像回転ではみ出た個所を補正する方法がわかりませんでした

という話について述べるとすると，
「はみ出さないだけの十分な大きさの画像バッファの上で作業すればよい」のではないでしょうか．
縦横共に元画像の対角線の長さ以上の大きさを有するバッファを用意すれば，その中に回転した元画像を収めることが可能なので，その上で作業を行えば良いです．